# controlling Event Structure from different subVI

Tags: structure, labview

I have a VI that communicates via USB to a machine in my laboratory; one of its VI main features the Event Structure, that only talks to the machine when a given command has its values changed.

I'd like to use this as a subVI in another task. Nonetheless, I couldn't find a way to make the two VIs talk to each other: only changes in the machine's main VI produces an output.

How can one control the Event Structure from a different subVI?

Comment: Do you mean 'when a given *control* has its value changed'?

Answer (score 1):

To use an event in a subVI you need to input a reference to your control from you main VI and from that reference register to the event generated by that control.

A more detailed explanation can be found here: [Detecting an Event in a Subvi from a Top Level VI](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/A882E27D1D7A949386256E0D0066B91A)

As a side point: From a design point of view, I don't think this is a handy way to go. Re-writing your machine subVi that it will take commands as input instead of events is probably not that much more work but will be more re-usable, extendable and maintainable in the future.